# Find an angle in a $100^\circ$-$40^\circ$-$40^\circ$ triangle without trigonometry (Langley-like solution?)

Tags: geometry

> In $\triangle ABC$, $A=100^\circ$ and $B=C=40^\circ$. $AB$ is produced to a point $D$ so that $B$ lies between $A$ and $D$ and $AD=BC$. Find $\angle BCD$.

We can find it easily with trigonometry by using sine and cosine rule but since the problem appears to be a variation of [Langley's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%E2%80%99s_Adventitious_Angles#The_problem) with an $80^\circ$-$80^\circ$-$20^\circ$ triangle, I suppose there must be a geometrical proof of it (or maybe not!).

Comment: If $B$ lies between $A$ and $D$, how can $AD=BD$?

Comment: @almagest i am sorry, its BC

Comment: I've found a proof here: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa06/Kitchings/cnkEMAT6600/100degisos/100degisos.html but it looks flawed.

Comment: Yes, it is flawed! But it might be fixable because, of course, $ADF$ is equilateral.

Comment: @Aretino oops... noticed now your comment. My answer is useless now.

Comment: @dfnu Your proof uses the same construction but is different, and I think it works.

Comment: @Georgecarlin Note that "The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted"."
See https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Robert Z but what if more than one answer make sense ?

Comment: @Georgecarlin You can vote for both and choose ONE as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

**A possible path**

Consider the Figure below. Draw $DA'$ so that $\angle ADA' = 60^\circ$ and $DA' \cong DA$, and let $E$ be the intersection of $AA'$ with $BC$.

[image]

1. Show that $\triangle AEC$ is isosceles, and thus $EC \cong AE$.
2. Demonstrate then that $BE \cong EA'$.
3. Use the above information and SAS cryterion to show that $\triangle ABE \cong \triangle A'CE$.
4. Therefore $AC\cong CA'$, $ADA'C$ is a *kite*, and $AA' \perp DC$.
5. Conclude that $\angle ADC = 30^\circ$ and $\angle BCD = 10^\circ$.

**Furhter hints**

> For 1., note that $\triangle ADA'$ is equilateral, therefore $\angle DAA' = 60^\circ$ and, consequently, $\angle A'AC \cong \angle BCA = 40^\circ$. In order to derive 2., observe that $BE + EC \cong AE + EA'$ (again use the fact that $\triangle ADA'$ is equilateral, plus the original hypothesis $AD \cong BC$), and $EC \cong AE$.

Comment: Fine! (+1). You should only explain the first two steps in more detail.

Comment: @Aretino sure, thanks! I'll add details in a spoiler box.